# Spark: flatMap/reduceByKey seems to be quite slow with Long keys on some distributions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using Spark to process some corpora and I need to count the occurrence of each 2-gram. I started with counting tuples `(wordID1, wordID2)` and it worked fine except for the large memory usage and gc overhead due to the substantial number of small tuple objects. Then I tried to pack a pair of `Int`s into a `Long`, and the gc overhead did reduce greatly, but the run time also increased several times.

I ran some small experiments with random data on different distributions. It seems that the performance issue only occurs on exponential distributed data.

```
// lines of word IDs
val data = (1 to 5000).par.map({ _ =>
  (1 to 1000) map { _ => (-1000 * Math.log(Random.nextDouble)).toInt }
}).seq

// count Tuples, fast
sc parallelize(data) flatMap { line =>
  val first = line.iterator
  val second = line.iterator.drop(1)
  for (pair <- first zip(second))
    yield (pair, 1L)
} reduceByKey { _ + _ } count()

// count Long, slow
sc parallelize(data) flatMap { line =>
  val first = line.iterator
  val second = line.iterator.drop(1)
  for ((a, b) <- first zip(second))
    yield ((a.toLong << 32) | b, 1L)
} reduceByKey { _ + _ } count()
```

The job is split into two stages, `flatMap()` and `count()`. When counting `Tuple2`s, `flatMap()` takes about 6s and `count()` takes about 2s, while when counting `Long`s, `flatMap()` takes 18s and `count()` takes 10s.

It doesn't make sense to me as `Long`s should impose less overhead than `Tuple2`. Does spark has some specializations for `Long` keys, which happen to perform even worse for some specific distributions?

Comment: Well... other than the performence, you are forgetting that the `Long` is not actually unsigned and you also have negative numbers in your keys. That `sign` bit will mess up your `left shift + bitwise or` predicatability. Thus `Long` approach can cause a lot of problems for you in this case.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh No, the keys will never be negative. This is the standard way to sample from an exponential distribution. The only possible flaw is that the sampling might overflow and result in 2147483647, which is also positive. Besides, the above code is just a demonstration, and valid word ids will be used in real world cases.

Comment: Ok. now we can move on to possible answer which is just a conjecture from my side. So you should already know that the `RDD`s are partitioned into multiple partitions and `reduceByKey` reshuffles those partitions with the new partition shceme being based on the `keys`. And the Huge `Long` numbers (keys spread in a huge range) are confusing the partition scheme to result in too many sparse partitions which is the cause of your bad performence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @SarveshKumarSingh's hint, I finally solved the problem. It is not the Spark's specialization for `Long` that trigger the issue, but Java's, and Spark doesn't address it properly.

[Java's `hashCode()` for `Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#hashCode--) is quite simple and strongly dependent on the two halves of the values, and Spark's default [`HashPartitioner`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/Partitioner.scala#L80) simply partition keys according their `hashCode()` values modulo the partition number. These make Spark's default partitioning quite sensitive to the distribution of `Long` keys, especially when the number of partitions is relatively small. And in my case, the situation deteriorates as the `Long` keys are constructed via concatenating pairs of `Int`s.

The solutions would be quite straightforward as we just need to somehow "shuffle" the keys, which makes the keys with similar frequencies distributed evenly.

The simplest way is to map each key into another unique value using [some perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), and convert it back when the original key is required. This approach involves only small code changes, but might not perform very well. I achieved performance similar to the count-by-tuple approach using the following mappings.

```
val newKey = oldKey * 6364136223846793005L + 1442695040888963407L
val oldKey = (newKey - 1442695040888963407L) * -4568919932995229531L
```

A more effective way is to substitute the default `HashPartitioner`. I used the following partitioner between `flatMap` and `reduceByKey` and achieved two times performance boost on real world data.

```
val prevRDD = // ... flatMap ...
val nParts = prevRDD.partitioner match {
  case Some(p) => p.numPartitions
  case None => prevRDD.partitions.size
}

prevRDD partitionBy (new Partitioner {
  override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = {
    val rawMod = LongHash(key.asInstanceOf[Long]) % numPartitions
    rawMod + (if (rawMod < 0) numPartitions else 0)
  }
  override def numPartitions: Int = nParts
}) reduceByKey { _ + _ }

def LongHash(v: Long) = { // the 64bit mix function from Murmurhash3
  var k = v
  k ^= k >> 33
  k *= 0xff51afd7ed558ccdL
  k ^= k >> 33
  k *= 0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53L
  k ^= k >> 33
  k.toInt
}
```